# Python 'if...continue' unexpectedly returns control to parent loop of current loop

Tags: python, file, csv, filenames, matching

I'm using Python in Visual Studio, stepping through the code in debug mode. After the first `if..continue` statement is checked, control returns to `for file..` as I expected.

However, on the 2nd pass through, when it drops down to the next `if..continue` statement, control returns to the start of the parent `for dir` loop, when I expected it to return to `for file..` again. Goal is to ignore any subdirectories and csv files with names of the form `_*.csv` (I'm hoping I don't have to dig into learning additional pattern matching stuff just now - if possible need to get a current small task taken care of):

```
for dir in os.listdir(masterDirPath):    
    currentDir = masterDirPath + dir

    # iterate through csv logs within current data folder, aggregating data
    for file in os.listdir(currentDir):

        path = os.path.join(currentDir, file)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            # skip directories
            continue

        if file.startswith('_'):
            # skip custom files
            continue

        if file.endswith(".csv"):
            # open log file
            .
            .
            .
```

Comment: Perhaps you had already looped through all files in that directory?

Comment: @Moberg - hi, thanks for the answer, but, no, I checked and double-checked that I'm looking in my test folder which intentionally contains a subdirectory, a valid 'csv' to be checked and a csv with the name '_testMe.csv'. Are you saying that from what you can tell, it *should* work as I expected?

Comment: add `print "-{}-".format(file)` at the beginning of your loop. Maybe your OS adds some whitespaces before/after file name. if so you can try `file = file.strip()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand -- you have a list of directories in os.listdir and a list of files in  each of those directories.

Ideally, you should load ONE directory into currentDir --> this  directory should go through each of the files.

I believe the control flow is affected because you're assigning the same currentDir to all your directories.

Try this:

```
for dir in os.listdir(masterDirPath):    
    currentDir = masterDirPath + dir

  # iterate through csv logs within current data folder, aggregating data
  ##### indent this part of your code #####

     for file in os.listdir(currentDir):
        path = os.path.join(currentDir, file)

        if os.path.isdir(path):
           # skip directories
           continue

        if file.startswith('_'):
           # skip custom files
           continue

        if file.endswith(".csv"):
          # open log file
          .
          .
          .
```

Comment: Thanks - I guess it was an indentation mistake - I copied and pasted your version in and it seems to be working fine now.